# SQL Query to return an altered view of existing table

Tags: sql

I'm unsure exactly how to phrase the question... but essentially, I have a table that has data stored in it similar to the following:

[image]

TYPE # = 219 is Person

TYPE # = 224 is Action

Ideally, I would like to run a query that would return the following results from the table above | Essentially, the name of the person along with a count of however many types:

[image]

I'm not asking for the solution outright (I know this site isn't for that) - I just don't know where to go or look for information related to this type of problem.  I'm new to writing SQL and, after spending quite a bit on this problem, I would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is a conditional aggregation with a self-join. The other way would be pivot.

```
select
    a.Name
    ,sum(case when b.NAME = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A
    ,sum(case when b.NAME = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as B
    ,sum(case when b.NAME = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as C
from
    SomeTable a
    inner join
    SomeTable b on 
    a.[RECORD NUM] = b.[RECORD NUM]
    and a.NAME <> b.NAME
where type_num = 219
group by
   a.NAME
```

You could also replace `and a.NAME <> b.NAME` with `and b.[TYPE NUM] = 224` or even `and a.[TYPE NUM]<> b.[TYPE NUM]` based on your post.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I was reading about self-joins and got confused with all the resources out there... I'm giving this a shot right now and will get back to you!

Comment: Worked like a charm - thank you so much!  I did have to add a where clause "WHERE TYPE_NUM = 219" to return only the people names though. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, no problem!  Take care :)